# How to include self-defined adapters in JSON class when using OpenAPI

Tags: java, openapi, openapi-generator, swagger-codegen

I am using OpenAPI to generate clients. I defined my own type adapters to do customized serialization/deserialization and imported/registered them in JSON.java class. But every time I run the generation, the lines of importing and registering self-defined type adapters get removed from JSON.java. I am wondering why and how I can avoid this. Thanks!

Here is the diff:

```
 import com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader;
 import com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter;
 import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
-import com.salesforce.sds.kms.client.Serialization.EkmAdapter; // DO NOT REMOVE
-import com.salesforce.sds.kms.client.Serialization.EkmSpecAdapter; // DO NOT REMOVE
 import io.gsonfire.GsonFireBuilder;
 import io.gsonfire.TypeSelector;
 
@@ -51,8 +49,6 @@ public class JSON {
     private OffsetDateTimeTypeAdapter offsetDateTimeTypeAdapter = new OffsetDateTimeTypeAdapter();
     private LocalDateTypeAdapter localDateTypeAdapter = new LocalDateTypeAdapter();
     private ByteArrayAdapter byteArrayAdapter = new ByteArrayAdapter();
-    private EkmSpecAdapter ekmSpecAdapter = new EkmSpecAdapter(); //DO NOT REMOVE
-    private EkmAdapter ekmAdapter = new EkmAdapter(); //DO NOT REMOVE
 
     public static GsonBuilder createGson() {
         GsonFireBuilder fireBuilder = new GsonFireBuilder()
@@ -104,8 +100,6 @@ public class JSON {
             .registerTypeAdapter(OffsetDateTime.class, offsetDateTimeTypeAdapter)
             .registerTypeAdapter(LocalDate.class, localDateTypeAdapter)
             .registerTypeAdapter(byte[].class, byteArrayAdapter)
-            .registerTypeAdapter(EkmSpec.class,ekmSpecAdapter) //DO NOT REMOVE. This is custom serialization
-            .registerTypeAdapter(Ekm.class,ekmAdapter) //DO NOT REMOVE. This is custom serialization
             .create();
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the similar issue with the below steps -

1. Add adapter in the template file - [JSON.mustache](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/resources/Java/JSON.mustache)
2. Define JSON.mustache template directory path in the Open API maven plugin.

```
...
<typeMappings>
   <typeMapping>OffsetDateTime=java.time.LocalDateTime</typeMapping>
</typeMappings>
<importMappings>
   <importMapping>java.time.OffsetDateTime=java.time.LocalDateTime</importMapping>
</importMappings>
<templateDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/templates</templateDirectory>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Please add the changes to the JSON.mustache file here, as the link could change